# Jenkins Pipeline: java.io.NotSerializableException with XmlUtil.serialize

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm facing an issue in my Jenkins pipeline where I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException` when using `XmlUtil.serialize`.

**Code Snippet:**

```
de updateFile() {
   def file = readFile(file: filePath)
   def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(file)

   ... update XML

   def modifiedXml = XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
   writeFile(file: filePath, text: modifiedXml)
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'agent-1'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Update File') {
            steps {
                updateFile()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

> Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

I am running this on another server as a Jenkins Agent. I tried `@NonCPS` also but it is not working also. So anybody can help me to resolve this?

Comment: Not an answer but the reason to try @NonCPS
https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/pipeline-the-pipeline-even-if-successful-ends-with-java-io-notserializableexception

 If you still need to keep an intermediate variable with a non serializable object, you need to **extract it into a method and annotate this method with @NonCPS**

Comment: @coz I think that should be the answer.

Comment: @coz It's not working because of [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/)

Comment: I'm not even stating that it works, but let add here the url for future users landing here from Internet searches https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/

Comment: @coz Yes, I understood what you mean by the above comment, but can't use **pipeline steps** with **@NonCPS** as stated in the Jenkins documentation. Btw thanks for the comment, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/, you
must not use pipeline steps in `@NonCPS`-ed methods -- that's probably
the reason why this solution fails for you.

However, the problem is indeed related to the CPS transformation I
think. You can work around it, however, without even using
`@NonCPS`. Moving the XML-related operations into a separate function
will do the trick. The following does work fine:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

filePath = 'test.xml'

def updateFile2(file) {
    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(file)

   //... update XML
   // e.g.
   // xml.bar = 'baz'

   def modifiedXml = XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
   return modifiedXml
}

def updateFile() {
    def file = readFile(file: filePath)
    def modifiedXml = updateFile2(file)
    writeFile(file: filePath, text: modifiedXml)
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'agent-1'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Update File') {
            steps {
                updateFile()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently, the CPS-transformation fails when you mix pipeline steps
and XML methods in the same function; putting the calls into different functions avoids that issue.

Comment: It's working, strange and interesting, moving that particular logic to a separate method was the solution. Now it's not complaining, I have no idea why is it, do you? Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: I was surprised as well : ) But then, that's not so uncommon with CPS. Jenkins (scripted) pipelines differ subtly from plain Groovy, and there's quite a few [issues](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54160?jql=%22Epic%20Link%22%20%3D%20JENKINS-35390) related to that -- often due to CPS transformation.  Sometimes it helps to drill down the code, play a bit with its structure and adding some`@NonCPS` sugar as needed. The particular root cause in this case isn't clear to me either. I'd be happy to see a CPS expert's comment here, explaining why _exactly_ my solution solves your problem : )

Comment: Yes, it would be great if someone could explain. However, thank you for the answer, I struggled for days for a solution. :)

Comment: It does not work because the groovy sandbox of Jenkins is not a full implementation, like it is detailed in the url pointed by @SomeGuy: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/

Comment: @coz, what critical construct of a full Groovy implementation is required by Some Guy's original script? It's not clear to me from the cited URL.